# Google GA not tracking event based Goal

Tags: google-analytics

I am using the following code;  Unfortunately, this is not recording any goals and i cannot see why.  When using the console to troubleshoot it is saying;
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.  It looks like this line is the problem (onClick=”ga(‘send’, ‘event’, { eventCategory:)but i cannot see why.  Any advice would be a great help.

Thanks

Dan

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-125974947-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-125974947-1');
onClick=”ga(‘send’, ‘event’, { eventCategory:
 ‘Contact’, eventAction: ‘Submit’, eventLabel:
 ‘Godwin Form’});”
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Events are coded a little differently with the new gtag syntax. If you test below, it may fix the issue:

```
gtag('event', 'Submit', {
  'event_category': 'Contact',
  'event_label': 'Godwin Form'
});
```

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for this.  I am still getting an error, its says it is on the line in red.  Any ideas.  Many thanks for all your help

Comment: <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-125974947-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('event', ‘Submit’, {
  'event_category': 'Contact',
  'event_label': ‘Godwin Form’});
</script>

</head>

<body>

Comment: gtag('event', ‘Submit’, {

Comment: It should still be in the onclick- was it moved to the head with the gtag initialization? Also, I think I see some curly quotes in there instead of straight quotes. I copied your original for the label and the smart quotes copied over as well. Edited*